# Gradle exec task with doLast fails

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to run an exec task only if a file has been updated since the last build. My initial attempt looked like this:

```
task generateLocalizedStrings(type:Exec) {
    ext.srcFile = file('../../../localization/language-files/en_US/wdmobilestringres.properties')
    ext.destDir = new File("src/main/res")
    inputs.file srcFile
    outputs.dir destDir

    doLast {
        println "Executing localization script"
        workingDir '../../../localization/'
        commandLine 'python', 'localizationScript.py'
    }
}
```

However, this fails with "execCommand == null!"

I found a workaround but I'd really prefer a proper solution.

```
task generateLocalizedStrings(type:Exec) {
    ext.srcFile = file('../../../localization/language-files/en_US/wdmobilestringres.properties')
    ext.destDir = new File("src/main/res")
    inputs.file srcFile
    outputs.dir destDir

    workingDir '../../../localization/'
    commandLine 'python', 'dummyScript.py'

    doLast {
        println "Executing localization script"
        workingDir '../../../localization/'
        commandLine 'python', 'localizationScript.py'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get rid of the `doLast` block, and instead configure `workingDir` and `commandLine` outside that block. (Configuring a task after it has run is too late.)

Comment: Will that still allow gradle to prevent the commandLine script from running if the inputs haven't changed?

Answer (score 18):

One option is to make the task a generic task and to explicitly call the `exec` dsl.  E.g. from this:

```
task("MyTask", type: Exec) {

    doLast {
        commandLine "your commandline"
    }
}
```

to this

```
task("MyTask") {

    doLast {
        exec {
            commandLine "your commandline"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use `exec` syntax to execute the command in `doLast`. It is the same as with `Exec` task type. For example in android i need to access the `versionName` field which is available only after sync:

```
task fetchConfig {
    doLast {
        String versionName = android.defaultConfig.versionName
        String appName = projectDir.toPath().fileName
        exec {
            // Path to folder where your script is located
            workingDir = "$projectDir/../../scripts"
            // insert script name
            executable = new File(workingDir, 'fetch_config.sh')
            args = ["-b$appName", "-v$versionName", "--test", "etc"]
        }
    }
}
```