# Gradle, task type: Exec - commandLine not work in onLast

Tags: gradle

I want execute some command from command line in gradle task(e.g. print all files in dir):

```
task dir(type: Exec) {
  def adbCommand = ["dir", "*.*"]
  commandLine adbCommand
  standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
  doLast {
    println ("result = " + standardOutput)
  }
}
```

It's work. OK. But when I put it on `onLast` section it's not work:

```
task dir(type: Exec) {
  doLast {
    def adbCommand = ["dir", "*.*"]
    commandLine adbCommand
    standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    println ("result = " + standardOutput)
  }
}
```

I get error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:dir'.

> execCommand == null!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle, commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'echo doLast!' does nothing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42055620/gradle-commandline-cmd-c-echo-dolast-does-nothing)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle exec task with doLast fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929645/gradle-exec-task-with-dolast-fails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is in the fact, that task of `Exec` should be configured during configuration phase of the build, otherwise your task will be not configured and fail.

In you first example everything works due to configuration happens at the configuratyion phase. Your second example tries to configure the task within `doLast` closure - right after the task is executed yet.

If you really need to execute something in `doLast`, you can use something like this, without creating special task:

```
task someTaskName {
    doLast {
        exec {
            commandLine adbCommand
        }
    }
}
```

Here is `exec`-specification used to execute some command and it's configured and executed at the same time.